# Confused about '+=' operator in C#

Tags: c#, operator-keyword

We were discussing something we saw in a coding class.  From what we recall, the instructor instantiated/created a variable somehow using += and C#.

I know it wasn't dealing with subscribing to events or adding y to x but didn't know if anyone out there could shed some light on what we might have seen?

Comment: I think in this case, you'd have to post a real code example to get a useful answer to your question.

Comment: Well, it must have been one of those two things as far as I know...

Comment: take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa7629ew.aspx

Answer (score 6):

The `+=` operator is overloaded for many types (as well as defined for built in types).  Really it's hard to tell just from your blurb what he was using it to do.

Add to existing integer:

```
x += 10;  // add 10 to existing value in x (x = x + 10)
```

Concatenate a string:

```
  name += ", Jr";   // adds ", Jr" suffix to a string.
```

Subsribe to an event

```
 myClass.OnSomeEvent += myEventHandler;  // adds myEventHandler to mutlicast delegate
```

So basically, in a nutshell, it just adds the current value to the existing one.  Without more information, can't be more specific...

Answer (score 0):

May be you saw something like this

```
int x = 10;

x += 10 means x = x + 10
```